# Can I add a stairway to my deck's cantilever?

Tags: deck

I am planning to modify my existing deck by adding a stairway. Currently the support post for the deck does not fall on the corner where I want to add the steps. The post stands about 5 ft back from the top of my proposed stairway. Do I need to add a post at the top of my proposed stairs?  Hoping that description makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: _mumblemumble a picture is worth 1000 words mumblemumble..._

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help. We have no idea what you intend to attach the stairs to, what it currently supports, and whether it's suitable to either the current or new load. Please take the [tour], then revise to help us help you.

Comment: How about a sketch with post locations, framing layout, and proposed stair location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding stairs at the tip of a cantilever with the support 5 feet away is a substantial load for the cantilever. Unless it has significant reserve strength beyond its design loading, then these stairs would require another two posts. You could consult an engineer to learn for sure whether the posts are necessary. They probably are, so I would save the money and add the posts. For specifics on the posts, see [IRC R507.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.3), [IRC R507.4](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.4), and in particular [IRC R507.5.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.5.2).

An engineer could tell you how many joists to sister with existing cantilevers so that you could support the stairs without posts. That's assuming that you have constraints that make posts undesirable or infeasible.

Comment: Where do you get a cantilever? This sounds like a _span_.

Comment: @isherwood, I placed my bet. Hopefully the question ends up matching. The hypothetical "would" language worries me, but assuming "existing" means "exists on paper," then "the post would be supporting about five feet of deck surface and then the stairway would start" suggests cantilever or midspan. The corner location contradicts midspan, leaving cantilever.